# Pragmatic design pattern

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns

I'm tearing into a poorly designed subsystem that has undergone two generations of "minimal changes" and has turned into a bloody mess.  One of the interesting messes I encountered was how the program goes about communicating overall program options into two threads it starts: it copies the program options into per-thread options and passes the per-thread options into the thread.  This seems dumb, since the program options are already stored in a global object.

I should probably point out these options are read-only once the command line and a configuration file have been processed, long before any threads are manipulated.  Changing either the configuration file or command options requires restarting the program.

I understand that the programmer who did this was reading Design Patterns at the time, and sort of got the "reduce unstated dependencies" mantra, but copying options from a global just seems like a waste of both time and space.

So, what's the suggested way to store overall program options in a manner that a thread can access them without copying them?

Answer (score 0):

You can just store options as they are (ensuring their lifetime is sufficient, e.g. on the heap) and pass a pointer to that object as an argument to threads.

On the other hand usually command line options are negligible in size and by not copying them you'll optimize practically nothing

Comment: That was my take on it too.  The way the design works, the settings can be modified as the program is running, but that happens in the context of the main thread of execution, and any time the options change, both threads become invalid, so the easy path is to stop the running threads and start new threads, passing in the updated options.